# Multiple errors occurred while posting image to my api

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to upload an image that I have taken to my API but when I tried to upload it, two errors occurred while running multiple sessions.

These are the errors that I have encountered.

## 1. '_File' is not a subtype of type 'String' in type cast

## 2. ═ Exception caught by animation library ═ Looking up a deactivated widget's ancestor is unsafe.

[image: error2]

And these are the code that is related to these errors.

## certification_tile.dart

```
        bool isLoading = false;
        void postImage() async {
          setState(() {
            isLoading = true;
          });

          try {
            String res = await ImageStoreMethods().uploadPost(
                descriptionController.text,
                file0!,
                challengeModel.challenges[widget.index][4]); //Sends to uploadPost function that is inside of image_store_methods.dart 
            if (res == 'success') {
              handleTap();
              setState(() {
                isLoading = false;
              });
              showSnackBar('Posted', context);
              clearImage();
            } else {
              setState(() {
                isLoading = false;
              });
              showSnackBar(res, context);
            }
          } catch (err) {
            showSnackBar(err.toString(), context);
          }
        }

        _imageSelect(BuildContext context) async {
          bool isAchieved = challengeModel.challenges[widget.index][3];

          if (currentUser == null) {
            showCupertinoDialog(
              context: context,
              builder: (context) {
                return CupertinoAlertDialog(
                  title: const Text(
                      "You have to log in before you submit the image"),
                  content: const Text("Please log in and try again"),
                  actions: [
                    CupertinoDialogAction(
                        isDefaultAction: true,
                        child: const Text("Ok"),
                        onPressed: () {
                          Navigator.pop(context);
                        })
                  ],
                );
              },
            );
          } else if (isAchieved) {
            return showSnackBar('You've already achieved this task', context);
          } else {
            return showDialog(
              context: context,
              builder: (context) {
                return SimpleDialog(
                  title: const Text('Select Image'),
                  children: [
                    SimpleDialogOption(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
                      child: const Text('Take a Photo'),
                      onPressed: () async {
                        Navigator.of(context).pop();
                        Uint8List file = await pickImage(ImageSource.camera);
                        setState(() {
                          file0 = file;
                        });
                        postImage();
                      },
                    ),
                    SimpleDialogOption(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
                      child: const Text('Choose From Gallery'),
                      onPressed: () async {
                        Navigator.of(context).pop();
                        Uint8List file = await pickImage(ImageSource.gallery);
                        setState(() {
                          file0 = file;
                        });
                        postImage();
                      },
                    ),
                    SimpleDialogOption(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
                      child: const Text('Cancel'),
                      onPressed: () async {
                        Navigator.of(context).pop();
                      },
                    )
                  ],
                );
              },
            );
          }
        }
```

## image_store_methods.dart

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:typed_data';
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:firebase_storage/firebase_storage.dart';

import 'package:uuid/uuid.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:app/models/post_model.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';

import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

class ImageStoreMethods {
  final FirebaseStorage _storage = FirebaseStorage.instance;
  final FirebaseFirestore _firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
  

  late int index;

  String currentUserUid = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid;

  Future<String> imageToStorage(Uint8List file, int index) async {
    String id = const Uuid().v1();

    
    Reference ref = _storage
        .ref()
        .child('users/$currentUserUid/${index.toString()}/')
        .child(id); // To specify the folder names for the post and post id
    

    // Reference is an object that represents a reference to a file or a directory in a cloud storage service such as firebase storage

    UploadTask uploadTask = ref.putData(
        file); // UploadTask is an object that represents a task for uploading a file to a cloud storage service such as firebase storage
    TaskSnapshot snapshot = await uploadTask; // Can monitor the upload progress
    String downloadUrl = await snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL();
    return downloadUrl;
  }

  
  Future<String> uploadPost(
      String description, Uint8List file, int index) async {
    String res = 'Some Error Occurred';
    String neterror = 'Network Error Occurred';

    String apiUrl =
        'http://Ip address of my API:8000/upload-images/?username=${currentUserUid}&challenge_name=${index.toString()}';
    Uri uri = Uri.parse(apiUrl);

    // Send the API request
    var response = await http.post(uri, body: {
      'image': File.fromRawPath(file),
    });

    // Handle the API response
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      
      var response = await http.get(uri);
      Map<String, dynamic> responseBodyMap = jsonDecode(response.body);
      if (responseBodyMap["success"] == true) {
        try {
          String photoUrl = await imageToStorage(file, index);
          String postId = const Uuid().v1();

          Post post = Post(
            
            postId: postId,
            datePublished: DateTime.now(),
            postUrl: photoUrl,
          );
          _firestore
              .collection('users/$currentUserUid/${index.toString()}/')
              .doc(postId)
              .set(
                post.toJson(),
              );
          res = 'success';
        } catch (err) {
          res = err.toString();
        }
        return res;
      } else {
        return responseBodyMap["reason"]; // Returns missing values
      }
    } else {
      return neterror;
    }
  }
}
```